# Combination of monotone and bounded sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ is a monotone and bounded sequence, prove that:

$b_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$ is also monotone and bounded.

What is the way to prove this?

Comment: Can you please give your thoughts and efforts toward the question? This will help people write answers that are relevant to your question; for example, can you apply the definition of monotonicity to say anything about $b_n$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: By definition, $b_n$ is monotone increasing if

$$b_{n + 1} \ge b_{n}$$ for all $n$; alternatively, this is true if

$$b_{n + 1} - b_n \ge 0$$

Start by subtracting, and see what happens. Monotonically decreasing is virtually identical.

---

Likewise, boundedness of $a_n$ means that there is a constant $M$ for which $|a_n| \le M$ for every $n$. Try erasing each of $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ in the definition of $b_n$ and replacing them with $M$.

Comment: I am not sure if b is also monotone, since we have manipulated sequence a. I dont know how the properties of a hold under this manipulation.